# Мультипроцессы и замки. Даже при наличии замка присутствуют гонки, так и должно быть?

Tags: python

Примеры использования lock c мультипроцессами, как в документации Phyton, так и в интернете, не обеспечивают защиту от гонок, при воспроизведении мной - вывод примера идет не в постоянном порядке, а при каждом запуске порядок вывода случайный.
Обеспечить постоянный порядок согласно списку можно только добавлением p.join() в конце, но тогда lock теряет смысл. В чем причина?
Потратил много времени, не понимаю.
Пример 1 взят с http://python-3.ru/page/multiprocessing.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def printer(item, lock):
"""
Выводим то что передали
"""
lock.acquire()
try:
    print(item)
finally:
    lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
lock = Lock()
items = ['tango', 'foxtrot', 10]

for item in items:
    p = Process(target=printer, args=(item, lock))
    p.start()
```

Пример кода из документации (https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) - 17.2.1.4. Synchronization between processes

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def f(l, i):
l.acquire()
try:
    print('hello world', i)
finally:
    l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
lock = Lock()

for num in range(10):
    Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()
```

Comment: @Эникейщик, вроде вопрос понятен, если пару раз прочитать...

Comment: Блокировки нужны для того, чтобы код **внутри блока** в разных потоках не дрался между собой за один и тот же ресурс. Упорядочивание выполнения - это другой вопрос. Да и зачем вам многопоточность, если вы хотите, чтобы код выполнялся **последовательно**? В общем, хотите последовательности исполнения - используйте `Pool.map` и не мучайтесь.

Comment: Изменил заминусованное описание согласно запросу Эникейщика (только я его не вижу больше).

Comment: @Сергей Вы неправильно понимаете, что такое `race condition`, перечитайте ещё раз. Это **не упорядочивание** выполнения кода, а наоборот - обеспечение того, что **код работает правильно при любом порядке выполнения**.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо, ясно. Особо спасибо за вопрос "зачем вам многопоточность, если вы хотите, чтобы код выполнялся последовательно?"- у меня тоже смысл действий несколько вызывал непонимание. Но тогда пример в официальной документации вообще не показателен, так как фраза "Without using the lock output from the different processes is liable to get all mixed up" никак на практике не подтверждается - вывод идет вперемешку что при Lock, что без него. Видимо, пример слишком простой, видно будет при сложной задаче?

Comment: @Сергей, добавь несколкьо команд вывода в заблокированный блок.

Comment: @Qwertiy, у меня и без lock не возникает проблем. Вывод с lock и без lock одинаков. Но идея понятна.

Comment: @Сергей, добавляй больше или добавляй задержки. Чтобы время между выводами было больше накладных расходов на запуск. Должны перемешаться строки от разных потоков. А если они перемешиваются даже с lock, то ты что-то делаешь не так.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, с задержками по 0.1с увидел, спасибо.  С lock не перемешивались, всё нормально было.

Comment: @Сергей Вывод ещё и буферизуется, поэтому всё несколько сложнее, можно попробовать ещё буферизацию вывода отключить, чтобы исключить хотя бы этот фактор :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Блокировки нужны не для того, чтобы обекспечить порядок междку блокировками, а для того, чтобы внутри заблокированных блоков не было одновременного исполнения.

> Вывод с lock и без lock одинаков.

Добавь несколько команд вывода в заблокированный блок. Причём, добавляй больше или добавляй задержки. Чтобы время между выводами было больше накладных расходов на запуск. Должны перемешаться строки от разных потоков. А если они перемешиваются даже с lock, то ты что-то делаешь не так.

Comment: Спасибо. И да, работают между процессами, конечно, в Python блокировки (там многое так же, как и в потоках). Я в документации проверил и код из неё добавил в вопрос.